# PHP-GD installed but not activated in RedHat 5.5 Enterprise

Tags: apache-2.2, php, redhat, lamp, gd

I don't know how the lamp server was installed. Launching a phpinfo() script i can read

```
--without-gd
```

even if i found the packages on the machine

```
root@mypc ~]# rpm -qa |grep php

php53-common-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1

php53-mysql-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1

php53-pdo-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1

php53-cli-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1

php53-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1



[root@mypc ~]# rpm -qa |grep gd

gd-2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2

sysklogd-1.4.1-46.el5

gd-2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2

gdbm-1.8.0-26.2.1
```

how can i activate php-gp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install GD with a

```
yum install php53-gd
```

Then when loading the phpinfo page look down the page. There should be a separate block for gd.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `yum install php5-gd`. Then just restart Apache with `service httpd restart` and you should be all set.